# Get router params from another component in Angular

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I'm using Angular4. I have some BarComponent that displays in the app.component template (for almost all pages, it's like menu bar). I want to get the router params that "belongs" to another component, not a children/child of the BarComponent.
For example, I have the route:

```
/some-section-name/:id{here may be sub-routes}
```

Can I get this :id param using the Angular methods within the BarComponent?
Structure is like:

```
|- app.component
   |- bar.component
   |- (lazy load) some section
       |- here is the component that has this :id param
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to face this problem many times, didn't find anything already provided by angular to solve it.

So I did a special service **routeReader** that receive any **Router** or **ActivatedRoute**, then take the `.root.snapshot` of it before exploring the whole `children` tree.

It may help you.

This is one of the method to read just the main branch, there is not a lot to change to read recursively the whole tree.

```
getParamsFromTop(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    let paramsMap = {};
    let routeCursor = route;
    while (routeCursor) {
      paramsMap = {...paramsMap, ...routeCursor.params};
      routeCursor = routeCursor.children[0];
    }
    return paramsMap;
  }
```

EDIT 1: Something like this should work if you put root route snapshot.

```
getParamsRecurse(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    let paramsMap = {...route.params};
    for (let i = 0; i < route.children.length; i++) {
      paramsMap = {...paramsMap, ...this.getParamsRecurse(route.children[i])};
    }
    return paramsMap;
  }
```

Comment: Interesting option, very good that it doesn't care about the nesting level. The bad moment - recursion, if app has a lot of childs. But thanks anyway, it helpful.