# Firebase Angular 6 Save child on existing Object

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to save a new form to an already existing list:
[image]

I made this like that:

```
    createNewTumeur(newTumeur: Tumeur) 
    {
           this.tumeurs.push(newTumeur);
           const id: string = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];     
 firebase.database().ref('/patients/'+id).child("tumeur").push(this.tumeurs);
  this.tumeurSubject.next(this.tumeurs);
  }
```

I dont have the value of 'id" an Idea ? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly. But if you want to skip the push ID (the key with `-LEP...`) you can just call `update):

```
firebase.database().ref('/patients/0').child("tumeur").update(this.tumeurs)
```

Calling `update()` will merge the properties from `this.tumeurs` with the existing data under `/patients/0/tumeur`.

Comment: I arrive recording when I write the "0" (index number) literally but what I want to do is to code the id that can take as 0,1,2,3 valuers)
This id is generated when a new patient is created and allows me to navigate to that specific patient. I would like to record the data for each patient ...
Am I clear enough?

Comment: Not really. I find it very hard to understand the goal here, which makes it hard to answer. But I *can* point out that using sequential indexes is not recommend in Firebase. For more on this see, https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: Each patient are one component that contain many form. I want save the forms into each patient database. What  the way for that? Thanks a lot

Comment: To add a child node to a location, call `push()` on the `DatabaseReference` for that location.

Comment: How can i obtain this databasereference?

Comment: `firebase.database().ref('/patients/0').child("tumeur")` is such a database reference.

Comment: Maybe my question is  how get the router params in my service ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857694/get-router-params-from-another-component-in-angular Can you help me ?

Comment: Maybe i can explain better here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50845281/firebase-angular-some-forms-same-route-activedroute